# geth console returns command not found on Mac

Tags: go-ethereum, mac-osx, installation

I am just getting started on ethereum programming on a Mac (OS Siera 10.12.6) and am trying to set up my environment. I am following the Ethereum.org installation [instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Mac).

I completed these steps to install geth I believe:

```
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install ethereum
```

and I'm now at the geth account and console steps.

However, I get this error:

```
geth account new
-bash: geth: command not found
```

and

```
geth console
-bash: geth: command not found
```

and when I cd to the directory ./Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/cmd/geth

and run it there I get the same error.

Also, these are the files I see in the directory and don't see one specifically for geth.

```
ls /Users/me/Library/Caches/Homebrew/ethereum--git/cmd/geth
accountcmd.go       genesis_test.go
accountcmd_test.go  main.go
bugcmd.go       misccmd.go
chaincmd.go     monitorcmd.go
config.go       run_test.go
consolecmd.go       testdata
consolecmd_test.go  usage.go
dao_test.go
```

Is there an installation step I still need to perform?

Is the documentation out of date? Are there some good, current documentation and tutorials you would recommend?

I do see this command: consolecmd.go

I'm not familiar with the go language but see quite a few files with the .go extension.

I don't think I have Go enabled because when I tried to cd to the directory it wasn't found:

```
cd /usr/local/go
-bash: cd: /usr/local/go: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to run brew update
brew upgrade and retry the installation process

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I didn't have /usr/local/bin included in my $PATH environment variable. The geth executable is located in this directory.

So I edited my profile: (vi .bash_profile)
and added it to the beginning of my directories in it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a similar problem and the solution is to add the geth.exe path to your .bash_profile file.

Another way is to solve is to find the geth.exe file in your laptop and copy it to usr/local/bin ( Make sure that usr/local/bin is already addded in your .bash_profile)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by adding it to your .bash_profile file

These are the steps

1. open terminal type cd
2. nano .bash_profile ( or ~/.bash_profile)
3. add this line
4. export PATH=/Users/Documents/go-ethereum/build/bin:$PATH
5. (This is your geth.exec file path)
6. source .bash_profile
7. geth